# Javascript: detect OS X "natural scroll" settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm facing an issue. For a project I'm doing I'm detecting the scrollwheel position and based on that I'm navigating to the next slide or not. A problem is, however, that some Mac users use "natural scroll" - inverting their scrolling on pages. This means that, for those users, I should use scroll in the other direction as trigger.

My question is; is there a way to detect in what direction the user is used to scroll? My initial idea was to track scrolling and see how scrollTop and scrollwheel relate to each other (i.e., I record mousewheel events and see which direction the page scrolls as a result). That, however, requires the user to scroll before I know what to do. Which doesn't work, as users first need to trigger a slide change.

I'm at a loss. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought: does it matter? In case your slides are horizontal it's quite arbritary if scrolling up should navigate left or right. And keeping this in mind: I guess that Mac users should be used to different scrolling directions (they have to change all the time, eg. when they use a PC in the city library...). I wouldn't spend too much time on this if I were you ;)

Comment: another thought: doesn't mac just invert te events that are triggered? So the browser wouldn't know anything about how the user scrolls, it just receives scroll-up and scroll-down events. (Mac user needed to test this ;))

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking... Page still goes down. Store the offset and compare with the previous, should tell you the direction regardless of the movement.

Comment: @giorgio it matters, as we're sliding up and down.. Mac doesnt trigger them inverted, unfortunately. Mousewheel events just show what happens on the trackpad or mousewheel. @ jorg, Unfortunately, that only works for the 2nd slide and on

Answer (score 8):

There's actually an easy answer, as long the Mac users are using Safari--

```
function myWheelEventHandler(event) {
  var deltaY = -event.wheelDeltaY;
  if (event.webkitDirectionInvertedFromDevice) deltaY = -deltaY;
  // use value for something
}
```

In this example, the value of deltaY will be positive when the user rolls the mouse wheel away from them (or the trackpad equivalent), and negative otherwise, regardless of the system-wide "natural" scroll setting.

In other words, if the webkitDirectionInvertedFromDevice property is present and has the value `true`, then you can be sure "natural" scrolling is enabled.  It even updates if the setting changes while your script is running.  The property is available for wheel events only (not scroll events).

If the property is not present, or is present but has the value "false" (which will always be the case in Chrome, due to a bug), then unfortunately you don't know if the scroll direction is reversed or not.

Your idea of testing to see how the page moves on wheel events may be the most robust solution.  You could create an invisible (empty) div in front of your slideshow, set to overflow:scroll, with a taller empty div inside it.  The first time you receive a wheel event on this div, you could then work out the scroll direction and trigger the appropriate slide change.