# Detect OS x "Natural Scroll Direction" in Chrome & FF using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, operating-system

I am facing an issue. I am trying to detect if an OS x user has "natural scroll direction" enabled when using chrome or FF. Currently, I am able to detect it if the user is on Safari using the following code.

```
$("html, body").bind({'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll onmousewheel touchmove scroll': function(e, delta) {
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0) {
    if(e.originalEvent.webkitDirectionInvertedFromDevice) {
        this.scrollTop += (delta);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}}});
```

This stackoverflow page helped me with the above solution for safari only. [Javascript: detect OS X "natural scroll" settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985500/javascript-detect-os-x-natural-scroll-settings)

Is there a possibility to detect it using chrome & FF. The reason I need it is because I want to force the user to scroll in "Inverse scroll direction", in other words when the user scroll downwards, I need the page to go do down.

Help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: shouldnt it be possible to listen to mousewheeldown and check which direction it scrolls`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really tricky one. Since the deltaY of the wheel event is set by the system (before it hits the web browser), so it is always positive for "scroll down" and negative for "scroll up".

It is *trivial* to inverse the scroll behavior, but we don't know if we need to or not. We could of course tell the user exactly what we're after and then reverse the scroll behavior depending on their answer, but that's not very elegant.

I don't know what your use case is, but if you're in 'desktop mode' and would consider making your app an Electron app then you could read the scroll behavior from the Mac OS system using the Node.js part of Electron, using a shell command:

```
defaults read -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection
```

I do realize that this is NOT what you want to hear... If I come up with something better I will let you know.

#### edit

As a *quick-and-dirty-solution*, assume that *almost all* Mac users have their scroll set to 'natural' (which is the system default since years back) and do:

```
if (navigator.platform = 'MacIntel') {
  window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX + e.deltaX, window.scrollY - e.deltaY);
  }, { passive: false });
}
```